# Adding custom HTTP headers to nginx X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, custom-headers, x-accel-redirect

I am serving restricted downloads in rails using `X-Accel-Redirect` with nginx. To validate my downloads in client app, i am trying to send the checksum in the non standard HTTP header `Content-MD5` to the `X-Accel-Redirect` request. But this is not working.

below the rails snippet used to do the redirection

```
headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/download_public/uploads/stories/' + params[:story_id] +'/' + params[:story_id] + '.zip'
            headers['X-Accel-Expires'] = 'max'
            checksum = Digest::MD5.file(Rails.root.dirname.to_s+'/public/uploads/stories/' + params[:story_id] +'/' + params[:story_id] + '.zip').hexdigest
            headers['Content-MD5'] = checksum
            request.session_options[:skip] = true
            render :nothing => true, :content_type => MIME::Types.type_for('.zip').first.content_type
```

This is the nginx section

```
location /download_public { 
 internal;
 proxy_pass_header Content-MD5;
 add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=315360000";
 add_header Content-Disposition "inline"; 
 alias /var/www/sss/public; 
}
```

This is not working apparently. I am not able to get the Content-MD5 header in my responses. Is there any way to pass my Content-MD5 header from rails?

I know there are ways to do that entirely in nginx, like compiling nginx with perl or lua and easily calculate the MD5 on the fly. But i dont want to do that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try `add_header Content-MD5 $upstream_content_md5;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, i got this error `nginx: [emerg] unknown "upstream_content_md5" variable`

Comment: Oops, it's `$upstream_http_content_md5`. See http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_http_

Comment: @AlexeyTen, it works.. :) please add this as answer, i ll accept it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `add_header Content-MD5 $upstream_http_content_md5;`

Since `X-Accel-Redirect` causes internal redirect nginx will not send returned headers, but it will keep them in [`$upstream_http_...`](http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_http_) variables. So you could use them.

Comment: same problem but with the aws s3 redirect. Could you please have a look at the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971724/nginx-pass-upstream-headers-to-the-remote-request . any help is much appreciated

Comment: If I am doing proxy_pass inside "internal" location - then $upstream_.. variables becomes empty. How to fix that?

Comment: @urmurmur ask new question

Comment: `nginx will not send returned headers` - seems  `Content-Type` is an exception, that header will be forwarded even without `add_header`

Answer (score 5):

I've tried accepted answer and it doesn't work for me. But this works:

```
 set $authorization "$upstream_http_authorization";
 proxy_set_header Authorization $authorization; # Pass on secret from back end
```

(copy-pasted from this article https://clubhouse.io/developer-how-to/how-to-use-internal-redirects-in-nginx/)

It's interesting that it's important to extract variable. This does not work for me:

```
 proxy_set_header Authorization "$upstream_http_authorization";
```

Comment: This answer is underrated. I can confirm that without the variable it does not work. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, interesting indeed that it behaves this way. I've read and re-read the nginx docs and I'm utterly unable to understand why it should do this. Anyone with answers, please speak up! :-D

Comment: For me it only works with: `more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: $upstream_http_content_security_policy";` (I needed to set the CSP header for a file served via `X-Accel-Redirect`.)