# Nginx pass upstream headers to the remote request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-s3, proxypass, x-accel-redirect

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507157/adding-custom-http-headers-to-nginx-x-accel-redirect) but doing `x-accel-redirect` on `aws s3` resource. The former tried to set the upstream headers to the local request. This works fine. But now i have moved my contents to the amazon s3 and i wanted to  implement the same restricted download to the s3 objects.

This is my nginx config

```
proxy_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;
passenger_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;

location ~* ^/download_zip/(.*) {
    internal;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;



    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length ""; 
    proxy_set_header Cookie ""; 

    proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-uid;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-mode;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-mtime;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-gid;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-version-id;
    proxy_hide_header accept-ranges;

    # Do not touch local disks when proxying
    # content to clients
    proxy_method GET;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    proxy_pass_header Content-MD5;
    add_header Content-MD5 $upstream_http_content_md5; 

   #  proxy_set_header Content-MD5 "123123123123123";


     proxy_pass https://a_b_c_assets.s3-east.amazonaws.com/$1$is_args$args; 


     }
```

and the rails part is

```
headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/download_zip/uploads/' + params[:story_id] +'/' +    params[:story_id] + '.zip?' + secure_part
headers['X-Accel-Expires'] = 'max'
headers['Content-MD5'] = checksum
```

Everything works fine except the `Content-MD5` is not passed to the proxied request.

Any help is really appreciated.

Another [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/382121/how-do-i-pass-headers-from-nginx-x-accel-redirect-back-to-the-browser) here

Comment: Here upstream headers are from amazon. You could use intermediate location to store first upstream header

Comment: hi @Alexey, right, i suspect that. Could you elaborate more on the intermediate location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proxy_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;
passenger_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;

# this is intermediate location that stores header
# to variable and rewrites to another location
location ^~ /download_zip/ {
    internal;
    set $Content_MD5 $upstream_http_content_md5;
    rewrite ^/(.+) /amazon_$1;
}

location ^~ /amazon_download_zip/ {
    internal;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;

    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length ""; 
    proxy_set_header Cookie ""; 

    proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-uid;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-mode;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-mtime;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-meta-gid;
    proxy_hide_header x-amz-version-id;
    proxy_hide_header accept-ranges;

    # Do not touch local disks when proxying
    # content to clients
    proxy_method GET;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    proxy_pass_header Content-MD5;
    add_header Content-MD5 $Content_MD5; 

    proxy_pass https://a_b_c_assets.s3-east.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

Comment: user could explain what changed from OPs code to his/hers