# Add header from backend to Nginx X-Accel-Redirect response

Tags: nginx, sendfile, x-accel-redirect

Problem:

I have a backend server, with an Nginx reverse-proxy, and a file store in S3.

Current behaviour is:

- Request comes from client
- Through Nginx to backend
- Backend returns response with `X-Accel-Redirect` header, pointing to S3
- Nginx internally redirects (possibly incorrect terminology) to S3
- Client receives file response

This is achieved with the following config, and is working correctly:

```
upstream platform {
    server localhost:8000;
}


server {
    error_log /dev/stderr;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    listen 80;

    location ~ ^/document_store/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*) {
        internal;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
        set $download_protocol $1;
        set $download_host $2;
        set $download_path $3;
        set $download_url $download_protocol://$download_host/$download_path;
        proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        add_header Content-Disposition $upstream_http_content_disposition;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass $download_url$is_args$args;
      }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://platform;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I would now like the behaviour to be this:

- Request comes from client
- Through Nginx to backend
- Backend returns response with `X-Accel-Redirect` header, pointing to S3, and a custom `X-Foo` header.
- Nginx internally redirects (possibly incorrect terminology) to S3
- Client receives file response, with `X-Foo` header from backend.

I have read several SO questions on this topic, and none of them seem to work.

I have tried referencing the `$upstream_http_x_foo` variable, but it seems to be empty. My understanding is that this is because the `upstream` has become S3, which does not provide this header. From a particular SO question ([Nginx pass upstream headers to the remote request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971724/nginx-pass-upstream-headers-to-the-remote-request/24989442#24989442)), I tried this:

```
upstream platform {
    server localhost:8000;
}

proxy_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;

server {
    error_log /dev/stderr;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    listen 80;

location ^~ /document_store/ {
    internal;
    set $custom_header_value $upstream_http_x_foo;
    rewrite ^/(.+) /redirect_$1;
}

    location ~ ^/redirect_document_store/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*) {
        resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
        set $download_protocol $1;
        set $download_host $2;
        set $download_path $3;
        set $download_url $download_protocol://$download_host/$download_path;
        proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        add_header Content-Disposition $upstream_http_content_disposition;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass_header X-Foo;
        add_header X-Foo $custom_header_value;
        proxy_pass $download_url$is_args$args;
      }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://platform;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

With the idea being that the value of the header is stored while the `upstream` is the backend, so that it can be later added when the `upstream` becomes S3.

This did not work either. There is no obvious error, the response simply did not contain the header. I cannot find any alternative options on S3 or in the docs. I am not particularly knowledgeable on Nginx, so it is possible that the solution above is simply incorrectly implemented by me.

Edit: I also tried adding the `add_header` directive below the `proxy_pass` directive, but that did not help either.